# `$container.imagesLoaded is not a function` error

Tags: jquery

So, I am getting `$container.imagesLoaded is not a function` error.

Here is the code which is located in header:

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {

    $(function () {

    'use strict';
    ////

    var $container = $('.grid');

        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            columnWidth: 100
          });
        });

        $container.infinitescroll({
          navSelector  : '#rh_nav_below',   
          nextSelector : '#rh_nav_below .rh_nav_next a',  
          itemSelector : '.grid-item',   
          loading: {
              finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
              img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
            }
          },             
          function( newElements ) {             
            var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });               
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){                
              $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
              $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
            });
          }
        );      

    ////

});

})(jQuery, this);
```

Then the footer has following js files:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
```

Is there something I am missing? is the location of file that's causing the problem?

Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

Followings are located at the footer and script is passed by anonymous function.
But still getting same error.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        var $container = $('.grid');

            $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
              $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                columnWidth: 100
              });
            });

            $container.infinitescroll({
              navSelector  : '#rh_nav_below',   
              nextSelector : '#rh_nav_below .rh_nav_next a',  
              itemSelector : '.grid-item',   
              loading: {
                  finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
                  img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
                }
              },             
              function( newElements ) {             
                var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });               
                $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){                
                  $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                  $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
                });
              }
            );      
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is imagesloaded.js? I don't see it in your examples.

Comment: It is in the masonry.pkgd.min.js (http://masonry.desandro.com/). Still somehow not working :P

Comment: Just making sure, you aren't using masonry 3.0.0 or newer, right? https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/changelog.md

Comment: I am using v.3.3.2. Do you think it has something to do with the version? That might explain something.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

imagesLoaded was unbundled from Masonry in version 3.0.0. You'll have to include it separately. http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Comment: Ah! =D Thank you for the help! I would not have figured it out. Thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 2):

Any code embedded in the page must reference code already referenced above it. Put your code after the script tags and it ought to work.

Make your footer look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script> 
<script> 
(function ($, root, undefined) {

    $(function () {

    'use strict';
    ////

    var $container = $('.grid');

        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            columnWidth: 100
          });
        });

        $container.infinitescroll({
          navSelector  : '#rh_nav_below',   
          nextSelector : '#rh_nav_below .rh_nav_next a',  
          itemSelector : '.grid-item',   
          loading: {
              finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
              img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
            }
          },             
          function( newElements ) {             
            var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });               
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){                
              $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
              $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
            });
          }
        );      

    ////

}); 
</script>
```

Essentially .imagesLoaded and .infiniteScroll don't exists until the script containing their definition has been loaded. This happens in a browser via script tags.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you be able to elaborate it a bit more for me? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I even used anonymous function to pass the script but still getting same error. This is frustrating. lol (See EDIT 1)