# Masonry not working on wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, masonry

I have been trying to make masonry work for hours on [this](http://109.68.161.119/~lousplek2/sfeer/) wordpress based website,
but i can't seem to figure out what exactly or where exactly the problem lies.

It seems that there's a jquery conflict, but i can't find where it is. 
I've tried the noConflict = doesn't work.

I've tried removing and adding different jquery versions.
I still get the indexOf(" ") error.

I've tried changing the $(document).ready to $(window).on('load') = nothing.

Event added imagesLoaded seperately = nopes.

I didn't make the website myself, which makes fixing problems on it even more frustrating.

I should probably add that woocommerce is also installed, but i'm not sure if that's part of the problem as well

Comment: can this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279419/container-imagesloaded-is-not-a-function-error

Comment: added that already, doesn't work :( @MandeepJain

Comment: There is an  error of noconflict

Comment: @VasimVanzara i removed it, but it doesn't look like it did much... can you help me out?

Comment: Yes,I can help you.

Comment: please check you have any masonry related plugin?

Comment: @VasimVanzara no, i didn't install a masonry related plugin

Comment: Its very difficult to me.